# Formatting mail body sent from Perl script to include lines and spaces

Tags: html, perl, email

I need to send an mail through my perl script:

```
use MIME::Lite;

GetOptions(
    'mail|m:s' =>\$recipients
)
my @recipients = split(/,/, $recipients);

sub sendmail {
    chomp @recipients;
    $to = "@recipients";
    $from = 'xyz@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Output';

    $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        From     => $from,
        To       => $to,
        Subject  => $subject,
        Data     => $mailbody
    );

    $msg->attr("content-type" => "text/html");
    $msg->send;
    print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
}
```

Here, I am appending output to mailbody like:

```
mailbody.=qq(Welcome\n);
```

which are statements containing output which has to be emailed.

How can I format this output to include additional lines and/or spaces? I think `\n` or even lots of spaces are also not accepted by **mailbody.=qq(Welcome\n);**, which results in a single line of content.

Comment: I've tidied the indentation in your code. You're very welcome, but please do it yourself in future. Clear indentation is an important tool to help people (including yourself!) to understand your code. If you're asking a group of strangers to read your code, it's only polite to make it as easier to understand as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said:

> ```
> "content-type" => "text/html"
> ```

This means you are writing HTML (or at least telling the email client that you are).

If you want to send plain text and format it using literal whitespace, then don't claim to send HTML!

```
 "content-type" => "text/plain"
```

If you want to send HTML, then write HTML which has the formatting you want (e.g. use `<p>...</p>` to indicate paragraphs, and `style="text-indent: 1em;"` to indent the first line of a block).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send HTML (as your `content-type` implies) then you need to use HTML tags (`<br>`, `<p>...</p>`, etc) to format your text.

If you want to use newlines to format your text, then you need to change your `content-type` to `text/plain`.

A few other suggestions:

- I wouldn't recommend MIME::Lite. These days, you should use something from the Email::* namespace - perhaps [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) or [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer) (I think I mentioned this yesterday).
- You should `chomp()` `$recipients` before splitting it into `@recipients`.
- You use `@recipients` inside `sendmail()`, but you don't pass the array to the subroutine. It's bad practice to use global variables within a subroutine - it renders your subroutine less portable and harder to maintain.
- MIME::Lite expects multiple recipients in a comma-separated string. So splitting `$recipients` into `@recipients` is pointless.